# Problem distributing XtraReport with docker in blazor server application

Tags: c#, blazor, report, devexpress, xtrareport

I use devexpress report in my blazor server application. The data is successfully uploaded to the devexpress report.

After running the project; I see the report file successfully and can export it.

But when I deploy the project with docker; I see the report file, but when I want to print it, I see a blank screen.

The report file appears normally in the development environment and I can export it.

However, when I deploy the application with Docker, the report appears, but when I want to export it, a blank page appears.

Program.cs

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options =>
    {
        options.DetailedErrors = true; // Hata ayiklama
    });





    #region Reporting TEST
    builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets(); //Radzen
    builder.Services.AddDevExpressBlazor();
    builder.Services.AddDevExpressServerSideBlazorReportViewer();
    #endregion



    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    app.Run();
```

.Razor page

```
    #region Report
    DxReportViewer? _reportViewer;
    XtraReport _report = XtraReport.FromFile(ApplicationConstants.CustomerReport);
    #endregion


    async Task ProcessMenu(RadzenSplitButtonItem item)
    {
        if (item != null && item.Value != null)
        {
            if (item.Value == "assignedUser")
            {
                await ShowUsersDialog();
            }
            else if (item.Value == "customerReport")
            {
                #region Report
                _report =  XtraReport.FromFile(ApplicationConstants.CustomerReport, true);
                _report.DataSource = _productDetailModelDto;
                _report.DataMember = "data";
                #endregion
                await ShowCustomerFormDialog();
            }
        }
    }


    .razor
     <DxReportViewer @ref="@_reportViewer" Report="@_report" Zoom="0.8"/>
```

When I run the application in the development environment on Kestrel, the report looks like this and I can export it as I wish.

[image]

But when I deploy the project with docker, I get an error as follows.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Docker support for XtraReports requires that you use the newer rendering libraries, as System.Drawing.Common libraries do not work in container/cloud environments. See: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/Reporting-Use-the-DevExpress-CrossPlatform-Drawing-Engine